# what is the use of void pointer in c++ if we can't access value without doing type conversion before dereferencing?

Tags: c++, void-pointers

Can anyone suggest me a situation where it's helpful and provides some flexibility in the code? 
Can we code a link list in c++ so that each of its nodes would contain different data type value?

Comment: i posted an answer, but actually I think the question needs clarification. suggesting a situation where void pointers would be the best solution is somehow going into the wrong direction, because usually you want to avoid using void pointers at (almost) any cost. Yes you can write a linked list with different data types, but there wont be any void pointers involved (well...maybe under the hood). So you basically have two unrealted questions that are both a bit too broad and unspecific

Comment: So this type of container(LinkedList having a different type of data in each node) can be implemented without using void pointers?

Comment: dont think in terms of implementation details, but think in terms of what interface you need. You never **need** a void pointer, what you **need** is type erasure and there are out-of-the-box types in the standard library that can do that for you

Answer (score 3):

There is (almost) no use of void pointers in (modern) c++. The cases where you need them are rare corner cases. Any example I can think of from the top of my head has a better alternative without void pointers. Really the only case is when you use an API that forces you to use void pointers, but even then you would wrap them up into something nicer.

How would you implement some container that can hold elements of different types? Consider taking a look at `std::any`, `std::variant` or the like.

Answer (score 2):

The primary use for void * is for passing pointers to functions that are not allowed to make assumptions about the type of the object and for returning untyped objects from functions. To use
such an object, we must use explicit type conversion.
Functions using void * pointers typically exist at the very lowest level of the system, where real
hardware resources are manipulated.

Comment: Well, in Linux _real hardware resources_ are manipulated through `unsigned long` to avoid accidentally casting a `void*` because that memory may be unmapped.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Why would the compiler's representation of a memory address make any difference?  If the memory is unmapped then touching it will generate a page fault (or exception) however you got there.

Comment: @PaulSanders `void*` converts to any pointer in C without a cast. `unsigned long` does not. `unsigned long` needs to be passed to a mapping function to get a `void*`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Ah yes, in C.  How soon we forget, sorry.